# python pandas in person class

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a person class that have 2 method, admin sign in and log in.

```
def admin_sign_in(self):#this instance make a csv file of admins username and pass
        info = {'user_name' : [self.username] , 'password' : [self.password]}
        self.admin_df = pd.read_csv('admin_file.csv',sep = ',')
        self.admin_df= pd.DataFrame(info)
        c = self.admin_df.index.values[-1]
        self.admin_df.loc[c+1 ,['user_name','password']]
        x = self.admin_df.to_csv('admin_file.csv',header= True ,index = False , mode = 'a')
        return x
```

but in csv file every object i make, saved with header and 0 index.
do you have any suggestion to manage it?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow"). In order for us to help you, it is necessary that you provide a minimal reproducible problem set consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and all relevant code necessary to reproduce the example. What you have provided falls short of this goal. Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set. See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details.

Comment: Why do you have this line in? `self.admin_df = pd.read_csv('admin_file.csv',sep = ',')`. It is directly overwritten in the next line. And the headers are there because youre setting `headeres=True`explicitly

Comment: if you append to file then you don't have to read it.

Answer (score 0):

If you run with `append` mode then you should run it `headeres=False`.

You could create (manully) file only with headers and later append new rows without headers

```
import pandas as pd

username = 'james_bond'
password = '007'

info = {
    'username': [username],
    'password': [password],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(info)
df.to_csv('admin_file.csv', header=False, index=False, mode='a')
```

It does't need to read previous content and use `loc[c+1, ...]` to append at the end.

---

Eventually you could write all without headers and add headers when you read it

```
df = pd.read_csv('admin_file.csv', names=['username', 'password'])
```

---

But it could be better to read previous content and check if username doesn't exist.